# What does it mean that Hmac is secure?

Tags: hash, sha, hmac, md5

I'm not taking about general collision attack on weak hash function such as MD5 or SHA-1. I'm wondering security of HMAC which is based on weak hash function

If there are key `k`, message `m`

```
Hmac(k,m) = hash(k`xor opad) || hash( (k` xor ipad) || m ) )
```

First Question, What does it mean that Hmac is secure?

1. Attacker cannot generates valid Hmac of given message m without knowing key
2. Attacker cannot finds collision that satisfy `Hmac(k',m') = Hmac(k,m) such k',m'`
3. Attacker can recover key `k`
4. others

And Second Question.

I'm reading about paper Transcript Collision

**Transcript Collision Attacks: Breaking Authentication in TLS,IKE, and SSH**

In this paper, They introduce Transcript collision
Attacker know `m1` and `m2`. And can find collision that satisfy
`hash(m1 || m2' ) == hash(m1' || m2 ) such m1' and m2'`

If adversary uses this Transcript Collision Attacks in weak hash function,
Can he also finds collision that satisfy `Hmac(k',m') = Hmac(k,m) such k',m'`??

Comment: hmac uses XOR, the hashing is more for uniformity than security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some research that strictly defines and proofs how HMAC is secure:

- [Keying Hash Functions for Message Authentication](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/kmd5.pdf)
- [The Exact PRF-Security of NMAC and HMAC](http://pub.ist.ac.at/crypto/pubs/GPR14.pdf)
- [New Proofs for NMAC and HMAC: Security without Collision-Resistance](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/043.pdf)

HMAC is a message authentication mechanism. This means that if an attacker changes a message, it can be detected because the HMAC no longer matches. This basically means that there is no message `m'` so that `HMAC(k, m') == HMAC(k, m)`. Note that `k` is the same here. If the attacker finds a collision with another key, so that `HMAC(k', m') == HMAC(k, m)`, this can not be used to spoof a message.

Answer (score 2):

Cryptographers have a generally accepted definition of MAC security: resistance to existential forgery under adaptive chosen-message attack.  Most cryptography textbooks cover this definition—for example, the [*Handbook of Applied Cryptography*](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) is a good source for this.  The *HAC* is available online, so you might want to browse [Chapter 9](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/).  It's a bit dated on the algorithms side, but the *definitions* are generally still applicable.

But to just coarsely expand this, the security goal for MACs is this.  Assume that:

1. The attacker doesn't know the defender's secret key;
2. The attacker can cause the defender to compute tags for messages of their choice;
3. The attacker can use the results of earlier queries to refine later ones.

Then a MAC is broken if an efficient attacker is able to forge any valid (message, tag) pair for a message they didn't query as part of #2.  (Note that proper formulations of this definition have some math attached to them quantifying the *effort* that the attacker puts into the attack and what *probability* of success is unacceptable.)

If the key is secret this definition implies the security goals that you list (see the *HAC* for more detail):

> 1. Attacker cannot generate valid Hmac of given message m without knowing key
> 2. Attacker cannot finds collision that satisfy Hmac(k',m') = Hmac(k,m) such k',m'
> 3. Attacker cannot recover key k

HMAC is designed to meet at least MAC security, but there are also proofs that HMAC supports another, stronger goal, called *PRF security* ("PRF" = [pseudorandom function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family)), which says that an efficient attacker can't tell the function apart from a randomly selected function of the same domain and range.

Comment: Why should HMAC be collision-resistant in that it is hard to find Hmac(k',m') = Hmac(k,m)? If the attacker finds a collision using another key, he can't use that to authenticate his spoofed message, right?